Cannot install timesynth with Poetry
When I run poetry add timesynth, I get the following error:
Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel

  error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['cmake', 'symengine'].

  To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,
  setuptools will not proceed with this build.

  If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages
  on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.
  Instead, consider the following options:

  1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)
  2. use a `src-layout`
  3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

  To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.

The problem is with the symengine package (specifically 0.4.0 version). I've tried editing pyproject.toml like so:
[tool.setuptools]
py-modules = []

As suggested in this SO answer, nothing changed. I've also included "timesynth" and "symengine" inside this list, no luck.
I've also tried including this codeblock:
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["symengine"]
include = ["pkg*", "symengine"]  # alternatively: `exclude = ["additional*"]`
namespaces = false

But it didn't help.
I'm trying to follow a book about timeseries, but I can't figure out how to install this package. I'm on Windows 11, and Python 3.11 if that matters.
